# Access MongoDB running in a container from local (host) machine [pymongo]

Tags: mongodb, docker, pymongo

I know this should have been a straight-forward issue as I did it before (but forgot how): I have my `MongoDB` running on a `docker container` as a service in my `docker-compose` that includes an `API` built with `FastAPI`. I'm able to connect to the database from my api container with the following code:

```py
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi

client = MongoClient('mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mongo:27017/', server_api=ServerApi('1'),
                     serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000)

client.server_info()
```

Now when I try to do the same from a Jupyter notebook on my local machine, I get this error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or
not known, Timeout: 5.0s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id:
63b6adb8b6aabb1624b50879, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription
('mongo', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo:27017:
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')>]>
```

This is my `docker-compose` configuration that used to work just fine when I was able to connect to my mongodb from local (so I don't think there is an issue here):

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    container_name: XXXXX
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./API/API.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./:/API"
      - type: bind
        source: XXXXX
        target: /Data
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
    env_file:
      - ./secrets/secrets.env      

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./secrets/secrets.env

  mongo-express:
    container_name: Mongo_Express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    env_file:
      - ./secrets/secrets.env
```

Comment: In your `jupyter` notebook running on `localhost`, if you use `'mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/'`, does it work?

Comment: no, it doesn't, same error. I decided to just use the API instead to get the data from the database in my Jupyter notebook as this is probably also best practice

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an answer below so that others with a similar question/issue will at least be presented with a workaround/alternative.

Comment: @rickhg12hs The workaround is to make an API, in my case with `FastAPI` but you can use anything else (e.g. `Flask`) with various endpoints to query the data from the database. I don't think I can write all of it in an answer. There are many accurate tutorials on FastAPI and/or Flask with Docker-compose out there that would be a better reading for anyone interested.